# Oracle SQL query Getting count of counts

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table of different films and every film has some copies:

```
inventory_id  film_id   store_id
     1           1         1
     2           1         1
     3           2         1
     4           2         1
```

I need to count the frequency of every film and count the amount of different films taht also have the same amount of copies, Like:

```
Copies    Counts
  2         2
```

I wrote this:

```
select DISTINCT COUNT(*) as Copies, 
       (select COUNT(*) from (select COUNT(*) as Copies from inventory
           group by film_id
           having store_id = 1)
       group by Copies
) as Counts from inventory
where store_id = 1
group by film_id
order by Copies DESC
```

And the result ist like:

```
Copies     Counts
   4         73
   3         73
   2         73
```

I don't understand why the Counts all have the same value. How can I do it right?

Comment: What you are attempting to do is far out of your SQL skills. The having clause is wrong, where is redundant. You should try to learn SQL gradually.

Comment: Yes I know.. I'm very new in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this description:

> I need to count the frequency of every film and count the amount of
>   different films that also have the same amount of copies

you would seem to want a histogram of histograms query:

```
select copies, count(*) as num_films, min(film_id), max(film_id) 
from (select film_id, count(*) as copies
      from inventory
      group by film_id
     ) f
group by cnt
order by cnt;
```

The following query is doing something quite different, including filtering by store.

Comment: Yes I also need to filter the store_id. I added where store_id = 1 before group by and it's right. Thanks!